# Should this be stored in a variable when referencing to an objects methods? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, this

Where I reference to a JavaScript object multiple times using `this`

```
var myObj = {
   method1 : function() {},
   method2 : function() {},
   method3 : function {},
   init : function() {
       this.method1();
       this.method2(); 
       this.method3();  
   }
};
```

Is there any kind of performance gain and should I store `this` in a variable? Like:

```
init : function() {
    var self = this;

    self.method1();
    self.method2(); 
    self.method3();  
}
```

Comment: You are clearly misunderstanding the use of `self`.

Comment: +1 for a well-written question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to store the `this` reference in a variable, unless you need to pass that context into a closure.

Here is an example of when you may need to pass the `this` pointer into a closure, such as a click event on an element that needs a reference to whatever the `this` pointer was pointing to in the outer, parent context of the event:

```
init : function() {

    $('.someElem').click( 
        (function(self) {
            return function() {
                self.method1();
                self.method2(); 
                self.method3();  
            }
        })(this)   // pass "this" into the "self" parameter as an argument
    );

}
```

In your case, you're needlessly creating a local variable and assigning it something when you really don't need to. It's redundant, and also creates a variable that isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does the same hold true if I have multiple calls to a property of the object - like: "this.property1.something" being called multiple times, or should I store these in variables?

Comment: The `this.property1.something` COULD benefit from being assigned to a local variable IF, `.something` is computed from the dom in an expensive way. Also, if you will be performing a series of manipulations and only need to 'persist' the result (again, most likely dom releated.)

Comment: @Andrew - That is a very good point! Thanks for pointing that out.